# android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell

Tags: java, android

I have a Framelayout and i want to have in it a Foldercell but i'm having this error and i don't know how to solve it.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.xbxvxe.rndfy, PID: 25023
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell
                      at com.xbxvxe.rndfy.fragment.FoldingCellListAdapter.getView(FoldingCellListAdapter.java:52)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2365)
                      at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1408)
                      at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1315)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:724)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2422)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1504)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1761)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I'm having the error in this line

```
cell = (FoldingCell) vi.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manageusers, parent, false);
```

My class is like this :

```
public class FoldingCellListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private HashSet<Integer> unfoldedIndexes = new HashSet<>();
    private View.OnClickListener defaultRequestBtnClickListener;

    public FoldingCellListAdapter(Context context, List<Item> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        // get item for selected view
        Item item = getItem(position);
        // if cell is exists - reuse it, if not - create the new one from resource
        FoldingCell cell = (FoldingCell) convertView;

        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (cell == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            //original
            LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            cell = (FoldingCell) vi.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manageusers, parent, false);

            // binding view parts to view holder
            viewHolder.price = cell.findViewById(R.id.title_price);
            viewHolder.time = cell.findViewById(R.id.title_time_label);
            viewHolder.date = cell.findViewById(R.id.title_date_label);
            viewHolder.fromAddress = cell.findViewById(R.id.title_from_address);
            viewHolder.toAddress = cell.findViewById(R.id.title_to_address);
            viewHolder.requestsCount = cell.findViewById(R.id.title_requests_count);
            viewHolder.pledgePrice = cell.findViewById(R.id.title_pledge);
            viewHolder.contentRequestBtn = cell.findViewById(R.id.content_request_btn);
            cell.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // for existing cell set valid valid state(without animation)
            if (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position)) {
                cell.unfold(true);
            } else {
                cell.fold(true);
            }
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) cell.getTag();
        }

        if (null == item)
            return cell;

        // bind data from selected element to view through view holder
        viewHolder.price.setText(item.getPrice());
        viewHolder.time.setText(item.getTime());
        viewHolder.date.setText(item.getDate());
        viewHolder.fromAddress.setText(item.getFromAddress());
        viewHolder.toAddress.setText(item.getToAddress());
        viewHolder.requestsCount.setText(String.valueOf(item.getRequestsCount()));
        viewHolder.pledgePrice.setText(item.getPledgePrice());

        // set custom btn handler for list item from that item
        if (item.getRequestBtnClickListener() != null) {
            viewHolder.contentRequestBtn.setOnClickListener(item.getRequestBtnClickListener());
        } else {
            // (optionally) add "default" handler if no handler found in item
            viewHolder.contentRequestBtn.setOnClickListener(defaultRequestBtnClickListener);
        }

        return cell;
    }


    // simple methods for register cell state changes
    public void registerToggle(int position) {
        if (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position))
            registerFold(position);
        else
            registerUnfold(position);
    }

    public void registerFold(int position) {
        unfoldedIndexes.remove(position);
    }

    public void registerUnfold(int position) {
        unfoldedIndexes.add(position);
    }

    public View.OnClickListener getDefaultRequestBtnClickListener() {
        return defaultRequestBtnClickListener;
    }

    public void setDefaultRequestBtnClickListener(View.OnClickListener defaultRequestBtnClickListener) {
        this.defaultRequestBtnClickListener = defaultRequestBtnClickListener;
    }

    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView price;
        TextView contentRequestBtn;
        TextView pledgePrice;
        TextView fromAddress;
        TextView toAddress;
        TextView requestsCount;
        TextView date;
        TextView time;
    }
}
```

And my layout is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_manageusers"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/listUsers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        tools:context=".fragment.ManageusersFragment"/>

    <com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:folding-cell="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cell"
        folding-cell:additionalFlipsCount="2"
        folding-cell:animationDuration="1300"
        folding-cell:backSideColor="@color/bgBackSideColor"
        folding-cell:cameraHeight="30">

        <!-- CONTENT (UNFOLDED) LAYOUT (MUST BE AT LEAST 2x times BIGGER than content layout bellow)-->
        <include layout="@layout/cell_content_layout" />

        <!-- TITLE (FOLDED) LAYOUT (MUST BE AT LEAST 2x times SMALLER than content layout above) -->
        <include layout="@layout/cell_title_layout" />

    </com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What this line means `FoldingCell cell = (FoldingCell) convertView;`

Comment: there is so much wrong with this code on so many levels. Please try reading the tutorial again you are following.

Comment: @KhaledLela convertView is used to reuse old view because as you know Adapter enables you to reuse some view with new data. and it's also for performance optimization by not recreating view that was created already because i have a view already created which made it possible for me by always going back to my drawer

Comment: @mudit_sen it's not a tutorial i'm following, i wanted to integrate the folding cell views with my code but it's not compatible with mine in so many levels and i don't know how to resolve it

Comment: fragment_manageusers is this the same layout file you have added in your question and inflating for the item in your list view.

Comment: @brxnzaz check my answer, for reusing you view with view holder, you have to check if `convertView` is null then inflate then create new view holder and set it as tag with `convertview`, if not null then get view holder object from convert view tag and update UI logic.

Comment: @mudit_sen yes it's the same

Comment: @KhaledLela okk i'll check it right now and see

Comment: @brxnzaz what you want is create new item layout file which contains your (R.id.title_price) ,R.id.title_time_label etc TextView fields. Then, you have to wrap this item_layout file in FoldingCell view. Then you have to inflate that file in your getView method of the adapter. You just cannot inflate same view which contains your listview in you adapter again.

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/
use this tutorial to create custom list view. You will eventually find your mistake. And get what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

```
> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell

- `FoldingCell` is a child of `FrameLayout` you have to inflate `convertView` as `View` then findById from `convertView` to get `FoldingCell`



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    // get item for selected view
    Item item = getItem(position);
    // if cell is exists - reuse it, if not - create the new one from resource
    // FoldingCell cell = (FoldingCell) convertView; // remove this line...

    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView  = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_manageruser, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();


        // binding view parts to view holder
        viewHolder.foldingCell = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cell);
        viewHolder.price = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_price);
        viewHolder.time = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_time_label);
        viewHolder.date = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_date_label);
        viewHolder.fromAddress = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_from_address);
        viewHolder.toAddress = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_to_address);
        viewHolder.requestsCount = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_requests_count);
        viewHolder.pledgePrice = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_pledge);
        viewHolder.contentRequestBtn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.content_request_btn);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder); // bind viewHolder with each view
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    // Update your UI logic...

   (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position)) { viewHolder.foldingCell.unfold(true);}
}
```

**Update**

```
// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView price;
    TextView contentRequestBtn;
    TextView pledgePrice;
    TextView fromAddress;
    TextView toAddress;
    TextView requestsCount;
    TextView date;
    TextView time;
    // Add FoldingCell here
    FoldingCell foldingCell;
}
```

**Update 2**

- Split `fragment_manageusers` layout with two layouts.

**fragmentusers.xml** that contains `ListView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment_manageusers"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/listUsers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    tools:context=".fragment.ManageusersFragment"/>

 </FrameLayout>
```

**list_item_manageruser.xml** that contains list item row view that will inflate covertView listView item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment_manageusers"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:folding-cell="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cell"
    folding-cell:additionalFlipsCount="2"
    folding-cell:animationDuration="1300"
    folding-cell:backSideColor="@color/bgBackSideColor"
    folding-cell:cameraHeight="30">

    <!-- CONTENT (UNFOLDED) LAYOUT (MUST BE AT LEAST 2x times BIGGER than content layout bellow)-->
    <include layout="@layout/cell_content_layout" />

    <!-- TITLE (FOLDED) LAYOUT (MUST BE AT LEAST 2x times SMALLER than content layout above) -->
    <include layout="@layout/cell_title_layout" />

</com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell>
 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I can't remove this line "FoldingCell cell = (FoldingCell) convertView;", because it's a class that i need in order to get those folding and unfolding motions which i'm using at the end like if (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position)) {
                cell.unfold(true);
            }

Comment: unfold(boolean) is a method and it need to be declared somewhere, that's the use of the line FoldingCell cell = (FoldingCell) convertView... it's not working and i don't know how to solve it i'm sorry

Comment: Please find out this line on my answer update `       (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position)) { viewHolder.foldingCell.unfold(true);}`

Comment: It's getting me this error : Attempt to read from field 'com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell com.xbxvxe.rndfy.fragment.FoldingCellListAdapter$ViewHolder.foldingCell' on a null object reference ... in the line " viewHolder.foldingCell.fold(true); "

Comment: Check my answer update, Please take care to learn about the difference between `ListView fragmentusers.xml ` and it's row item `list_item_manageruser.xml` that will inflate in getView method `            convertView  = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_manageruser, parent, false);`

Comment: It's not working even though i split it into two views, i tried it before and it lead me to nothing... i'll just change everything and see what will i get.... Thank you so much for your help